# android push notifications library with google cloud messaging

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-messaging

i am working on an android using GCM  application and adding support libraries,i added the following to my gradle

i added a plugin

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'    
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

and dependencies: i added:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'    
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
```

but it brings an error

```
Error:(3, 0) Plugin with id 'com.google.gms.google-services' not found.
```

and yet i see the plugin added. how to i correct it thank you

Comment: `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` put this on bottom of your gradle file. not on top

Comment: should i put it in the dependencies section, thank you

Comment: Not put it all the way at the bottom

Answer (score 0):

In your project level `build.gradle` add like following:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
```

While your App level `build.gradle` should look like this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.3.0"
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Make sure to add `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` as last line in your app level gradle file.

Comment: when synchronising my project hey brought for me this error

Comment: Error:Could not run build action using Gradle installation 'E:\COLLECTION\installs\studio\gradle\gradle-2.10'.

Comment: I am using latest `gradle:2.1.2` in my project. You can either update your version or use the earlier version as you were in your project.

Answer (score 0):

You should only apply the com.android.application plugin.

Applying the java plugin as well will result in a build error.
Reference : http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide

The dependencies you have added are fine. You can remove the "apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'" entry.